# How Can I Concatenate Only Unique Columns in MySQL for Every Row?

Tags: mysql, set, mariadb, distinct, concatenation

#### How can I concatenate only the unique columns for the columns specified for every row in MySQL?

**Table 'Example':**

Consider the following table named `example`:

```
* -------------------------- *
| Id | Col_A | Col_B | Col_C |
| -------------------------- |
| 0  | foo   | bar   | qux   |
| 1  | foo   | foo   | bar   |
| 2  | foo   | qux   | qux   |
| 3  | foo   | foo   | foo   |
* -------------------------- *
```

**Attempt:**

I would like to concatenate only the values in `Col_A`, `Col_B`, and `Col_C` that are unique (only the unique set). This was my attempt:

```
SELECT Id,
       CONCAT_WS(',', DISTINCT Col_A, Col_B, Col_C) UniqueColumnSet
  FROM Example
```

**Expected Result:**

```
* -------------------- *
| Id | UniqueColumnSet |
| -------------------- |
| 0  | foo,bar,qux     |
| 1  | foo,bar         |
| 2  | foo,qux         |
| 3  | foo             |
* -------------------- *
```

**Error Received:**

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DISTINCT Col_A, Col_B, Col_C) UniqueColumnSet
>     FROM Example LIMIT 0, 25' at line 2

I am aware that you cannot use `DISTINCT` like this in `CONCAT_WS`. What would be the most efficient method to obtain the expected result?

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor schema design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of approaches I can think of.

One would be to use expression in place of Col_B that checks to to see if Col_B matches Col_A, and return a NULL if it does.  Same thing for an expression to check Col_C to see if it matches Col_A or Col_B.

CONCAT_WS ignores NULL values,  so something like this:

```
SELECT t.id
     , CONCAT_WS(','
           , t.Col_A 
           , IF(t.Col_B IN (t.Col_A), NULL, t.Col_B) 
           , IF(t.Col_C IN (t.Col_A,t.Col_B), NULL, t.Col_C)
       ) AS UniqueColumnSet
  FROM `example` t
 ORDER BY t.id
```

---

Not shown in the example data is a case where the duplicate values are not contiguous, for example

```
bar foo bar
```

the query above assumes that we'd want to return

```
bar,foo
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `UNION` to pivot them into the same column, then use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to concatenate them. `UNION` will remove duplicates by default.

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(col) AS UniqueColumnSet
FROM (
    SELECT id, col_a AS col
    FROM Example
    UNION
    SELECT id, col_b AS col
    FROM Example
    UNION
    SELECT id, col_c AS col
    FROM Example
) AS x
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer Barmar's solution, since it's the most readable for me. But this should work too:

```
select id, concat_ws(',',
  Col_A,
  NULLIF(Col_B, Col_A),               -- NULL if Col_B = Col_A
  NULLIF(NULLIF(Col_C, Col_A), Col_B) -- NULL if Col_C = Col_A or Col_C = Col_B
) as UniqueColumnSet 
from Example
```

[db-fidle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e3M7CXbPMZLZHh7HSSDWo1/0)

If you are fine with a JSON array as result, you can try this "hack":

```
select id, json_keys(json_object(Col_A, '', Col_B, '', Col_C, '')) as UniqueColumnSet
from Example;
```

Result:

```
| id  | UniqueColumnSet       |
| --- | --------------------- |
| 0   | ["bar", "foo", "qux"] |
| 1   | ["bar", "foo"]        |
| 2   | ["foo", "qux"]        |
| 3   | ["foo"]               |
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ds931KVnKm1zKbiKCG1EmK/0)